# Гардина как палка

Tags: значение-слов

В моём окружении все люди называют гардиной карниз для занавесок. Большинство ресурсов в сети, посвящённых этой теме, категорично высказываются против такого употребления, ссылаясь на то, что гардиной может быть только ткань, но никак не палка.

Однако, например, "Викисловарь" уже зафиксировал второе значение этого слова. А что насчёт других источников? Нет ли авторитетных источников, которые уже признали неправильное народное употреблением допустимой нормой языка?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нет, в нормативных словарях такого значения не зафиксировано.
(Справка: проверять информацию сразу по нескольким словарям можно [здесь](https://gufo.me) и [здесь](https://academic.ru).)